# Disable log4j console logging in linux

Tags: java, linux, log4j

I have my log4j.properties file as -

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Problem is, log messages are also getting printed on console. How can I disable that? I have read some of the posts here on stackoverflow but other users were facing issues because they defined the consoleAppender into their file but I haven't defined it in my log4j.properties file and still it displays it on console.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing additivity false. like below in your property file.

   `log4j.additivity=false`

Answer (score -1):

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
#hide the Log4jMemoryAppender from console
log4j.logger.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.MemoryAppender= ERROR, MEMORY_APPENDER
log4j.appender.MEMORY_APPENDER=nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.MemoryAppender.Log4jMemoryAppender
log4j.additivity.rootLogger = false
log4j.additivity.console = false
log4j.additivity.MEMORY_APPENDER=false
```